# Rの文字列処理： ある文字列で挟まれた部分を取り出したい

Tags: r

Rを使った文字列処理に関する質問です．

例えば

```
"XhogehogeY"
```

という文字列があったときに，
XとYを指定して"hogehoge"を取り出すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

教えて下さいお願いします．

追記-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
様々な回答ありがとうございます．
一旦は解決したのですが，文字列に日本語を含む場合にエラーが出たので改めて質問させてください．

文字列

```
"pogepoge開始:hogehoge終pogepoge終"
```

から"hogehoge"を取り出したいです．
しかし，

```
> str_extract("pogepoge開始:hogehoge終pogepoge終","(?<=開始:)(.*?)(?=終)")
[1] NA
```

として切り出そうとするとNAとなるのです．

```
> str_detect("pogepoge開始:hogehoge終pogepoge終","(?<=開始:)(.*?)(?=終)")
[1] TRUE
```

となっているので確かにマッチしているはずですが．．．

以下のように"始:"としたら切り出せました．

```
> str_extract("pogepoge開始:hogehoge終pogepoge終","(?<=始:)(.*?)(?=終)")
[1] "hogehoge"
```

しかし"始:"では他の文字列とマッチしてしまうので，"開始:"で切り出したいのです．

Comment: 日本語を含む文字列の場合を追記しました．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_detect()` と `str_extract()` をソースコード上で調べてみました。

# stringr 1.0.0 は [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) の wrapper です。

**str_detect():stringi/src/stri_search_regex_detect.cpp**

```c++
StriContainerUTF16 str_cont(str, vectorize_length);
//   StriContainerUTF8 str_cont(str, vectorize_length); // utext_openUTF8, see below
StriContainerRegexPattern pattern_cont(pattern, vectorize_length, pattern_flags);
```

**str_extract():stringi/src/stri_search_regex_extract.cpp**

```c++
StriContainerUTF8 str_cont(str, vectorize_length);
StriContainerRegexPattern pattern_cont(pattern, vectorize_length, pattern_flags);
```

`str_detect()` では処理対象の文字列を格納する変数 `str_cont` の型が `StriContainerUTF8` から `StriContainerUTF16` に変更されているのですが、`str_extract()` ではそのままです。

近い将来、`str_extract()` も `StriContainerUTF16` に変更されるかも知れません(pull request を出す方が良いのかも知れませんが…)。

stringr を使わない方法でも良いのであれば、前の回答に書いておいた方法を使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
> unlist(strsplit("pogepoge開始:hogehoge終pogepoge終", "開始:|終"))[2]
[1] "hogehoge"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます．関数の仕様なのですね．

`unlist(strsplit("pogepoge開始:hogehoge終pogepoge終", "開始:|終"))[2]`でどうか，とのことですが，実際に対象としている文字列はNAや空白，改行を含む長い文字列なのです．

だからかも知れませんが，

`> unlist(strsplit(txt, "開始:|終"))[2]`
`Error in strsplit(txt, "開始:|終") : non-character argument`

となりました．

また`txt`は`list`なのですがそれは関係するのでしょうか

Comment: `txt` が `list` であれば `stringr::str_split` の方が良いかと思います。`str_split` は `str_detect` と同様に `StriContainerUTF16` に変更されていますので、期待通りの結果を返してくれます。例えば、`sapply(str_split(txt, "開始:|終"), function(r) r[2])` とします。

Comment: `txt <- txt[[1]]`として`txt`を`character`にし，`for(i in 1:length(txt)) { str_detect(txt[i],"(?<=開始:)(.*?)(?=終)") }`として対象の文字列が含まれる要素番号を検出して，対象の文字列`"X始:ZZZ終 XXX:YYY終 開始:hogehoge終"`を取り出し，`strsplit`を使って目的の文字列を抽出できました．

Answer (score 2):

同じ `{stringr}`パッケージの`str_replace()`関数を使った抽出パターンをかんがえてみました。今回の場合、文字列のはじめにX、最後にYということでしたので、それらを空白で置換するという方法です。

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all("XhogehogeY", "^X|Y$", "")
# [1] "hogehoge"
```

コメントのパターンに関しては、つぎのようにすることで対象の文字列を抽出出来ました。

```
str_replace_all("STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND", "^START|END.*", "")
# 文字列の始めのSTART、最初のEND以降を空白で置換
# [1] "hogehoge"
```

外部パッケージを利用しないパターンは、`gsub()`を使って同様につぎのようにします。

```
gsub("^X|Y$", "", "XhogeY")
gsub("^START|END.*", "", "STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND")
```

Answer (score 1):

これは、正規表現の「肯定的先読み（positive lookahead）」「肯定的後読み（positive lookbehind）」を使うとうまくマッチさせることができます。
参考：http://d.hatena.ne.jp/a_bicky/20100530/1275195072

例えば、stringrというパッケージだとこの正規表現が使えます。

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("XhogehogeY", "(?<=X)(.*)(?=Y)")
#> [1] "hogehoge"
```

（標準の関数でも使えるのかもしれませんが、よくわかりませんでした。すみません...）

Comment: ありがとうございます．大変助かります．

ただ，"STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND"とあった場合にはどうしたら"hogehoge"を取り出せますか？

    str_extract("STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND", "(?<=START)(.*)(?=END)")

ではNANが帰ってきました

Comment: @kamioka stringr version 1.0.0 では `"hogehogeENDpogepoge"` が返ります。なお、`str_extract("STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND", "(?<=START)(.*?)(?=END)")` とすると(`(.*)` を `(.*?)` に変更)、`"hogehoge"` が返ります。両指定子に `?` を付けることで最短マッチになります。付けないと最長マッチになります。

Answer (score 1):

> "STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND"とあった場合にはどうしたら"hogehoge"を取り出せますか？

既に回答が付いていますが、別の方法で処理してみます。

R の `sub()` や `gsub()` では perl の正規表現(肯定的先読み・後読みなど)を使う事ができます。

```
> ?sub
sub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, ...
gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, ...
regexpr(pattern, text, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, ...
                 :
perl: logical. Should perl-compatible regexps be used?
                 :
```

ここでは `regexpr()` を使ってみます。

```
> txt <- "STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND"
> m <- regexpr("(?<=START).*?(?=END)", txt, perl=T)
> substr(txt, m, m + attr(m, "match.length") - 1)
[1] "hogehoge"
```

その他、`strsplit()` を使う方法もあります。

```
> unlist(strsplit("STARThogehogeENDpogepogeEND", "START|END"))[2]
[1] "hogehoge"
```